Is Hilbert transform of locally integrable function also locally integrable?
For a locally integrable function $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb C$, define the Hilbert transform $Hf$ as $$Hf(x)=\lim_{\epsilon\to +0, R\to\infty\qquad}\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{\epsilon<|x-y|<R}\qquad\frac{f(y)}{x-y}dy,$$ if the limit exists for all $x$.
Then, I wonder whether $Hf$ is also locally integrable or not.
I have, for compact $K\subset\mathbb R$,
\begin{align}
\int_K|Hf(x)|dx
&=\int_K\lim \frac{1}{\pi} \left|\int_{\epsilon<|x-y|<R}\qquad\frac{f(y)}{x-y}dy\right|dx\\
&\leqq \underline\lim\frac{1}{\pi}\int_K\int_{\epsilon<|x-y|<R}\qquad\left|\frac{f(y)}{x-y}\right|dydx\\
&\leqq \underline\lim\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-k}^k\int_{\epsilon<|x-y|<R}\qquad\left|\frac{f(y)}{x-y}\right|dydx,
\end{align}
where I took $k>0$ s.t. $K\subset [-k,k]$.
So I want to bound the term : $$\underline\lim\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-k}^k\int_{\epsilon<|x-y|<R}\qquad\left|\frac{f(y)}{x-y}\right|dydx.$$
Maybe the key is the use of locally integrability of $f$. Does anyone come up with some idea ?
